# Language C: pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [2]'

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to replace all the letters (from 1st position) of a C string but I get this error:

```
pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [2]'
```

what does it means and what's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char parola1[50] = "Parola 1";
    char parola2[50];
    int i;

    strcpy(parola2, parola1);

    for (i = 1; i < strlen(parola2); i++) {
        parola1[i] = "-";
    }
    printf("La parola 1 contiene la parola %s\n", parola1);
    printf("La parola 2 contiene la parola %s\n", parola2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use single quotes for character constants. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: The *first* position in `parola1` is `0`, not `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"-"` is an array of characters. If you want to assign an character, use `'-'`

Note that using `strlen()` is loop condition will lead to loss of performance.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char parola1[50]="Parola 1";
  char parola2[50];

  int i, len;


  strcpy(parola2,parola1);

  for(i=1, len = strlen(parola2);i<len;i++)
  {
    parola1[i]='-';

  }
  printf("La parola 1 contiene la parola %s\n", parola1);
  printf("La parola 2 contiene la parola %s\n", parola2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compilers can perform loop invariant optimization so this may not lead to loss of performance

Answer (score 1):

For starters this loop looks strange

```
  for(i=1;i<strlen(parola2);i++)
      ^^^          ^^^^^^^
  {
    parola1[i]="-";
    ^^^^^^^    ^^^
  }
```

In the condition of the loop there is used variable `parola2` while within the body of the loop there is used variable `parole1`

Also it is not clear whether you indeed want that the index starts from 1 and not from 0.

In this statement

```
    parola1[i]="-";
```

you are trying to assign string literal `"-"` that has type `char[2]` and is converted to pointer to its first element to object `parola1[i]` of type `char`

And there is no need to call function `strlen` that to perform the loop.

I suppose what you want is the following

```
strcpy( parola2, parola1 );

for( i = 0; parola1[i] != '\0'; i++ )
     ^^^^^
{
    parola1[i] = '-';
                 ^^^^
}
```